# Construct 3 Xcode App Build Successful but App crashing on iPhone

Tags: xcode, crash, construct-3

I successfully built my app with some warnings that seem irrelevant. The issue at hand is that when I get into the actual "game" the app crashes and goes back to the loading screen. I used construct 3 to build the app. Here is the build log

2023-10-08 20:17:31.601556-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Process] 0x115002050 - [PID=23003] WebProcessProxy::didClose: (web process 0 crash) 2023-10-08 20:17:31.601721-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Process] 0x115002050 - [PID=23003] WebProcessProxy::processDidTerminateOrFailedToLaunch: reason=Crash 2023-10-08 20:17:31.601795-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11301c120 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process because PID 0 is invalid 2023-10-08 20:17:31.602745-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Process] 0x10700b018 - [pageProxyID=14, webPageID=15, PID=23003] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 23003), reason=Crash 2023-10-08 20:17:31.602816-0400 TigerRun[22954:6273277] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11301c120 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=0, error: (null) 2023-10-08 20:17:31.605461-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Loading] 0x10700b018 - [pageProxyID=14, webPageID=15, PID=23003] WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason=Crash 2023-10-08 20:17:31.641789-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Process] 0x1130704e0 - GPUProcessProxy::gpuProcessExited: reason=IdleExit 2023-10-08 20:17:31.641854-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Process] 0x115001ca0 - [PID=0] WebProcessProxy::gpuProcessExited: reason=IdleExit 2023-10-08 20:17:31.831522-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] IAB.close() called but it was already closed. 2023-10-08 20:17:31.979590-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Facebook] No App ID provided. Please enter an App ID before using the object. 2023-10-08 20:17:36.224691-0400 TigerRun[22954:6274282] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)}> 2023-10-08 20:17:36.224732-0400 TigerRun[22954:6274282] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11304c9a0 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebKit Media Playback' for process with PID=23005, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)} 2023-10-08 20:17:36.227852-0400 TigerRun[22954:6274282] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)}> 2023-10-08 20:17:36.227873-0400 TigerRun[22954:6274282] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11304ca40 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebKit Media Playback' for process with PID=22954, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)} 2023-10-08 20:17:36.229752-0400 TigerRun[22954:6274282] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)}> 2023-10-08 20:17:36.229771-0400 TigerRun[22954:6274282] [ProcessSuspension] 0x11304ca90 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebKit Media Playback' for process with PID=23007, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=(originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit AND originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.multitasking.systemappassertions)} 2023-10-08 20:17:41.215370-0400 TigerRun[22954:6268734] [Construct] Suspending